# AngularJS pass Javascript object to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a Javascript object into my AngularJS controller and having no luck.

I've tried passing it into an `init` function:

```
<div ng-controller="GalleryController" ng-init="init(JSOBJ)">
```

And on my controller side:

```
$scope.init = function(_JSOBJ)
{
    $scope.externalObj = _JSOBJ;
    console.log("My Object.attribute : " + _JSOBJ.attribute );
};
```

Though the above doesn't seem to work.

Alternatively, I've tried pulling the attribute from the AngularJS controller that I am interested in for use in an inline `<script>` tag:

```
var JSOBJ.parameter = $('[ng-controller="GalleryController"]').scope().attribute ;
console.log("My Object.parameter: " + JSOBJ.attribute );
```

Can anyone tell me: what is the best practice regarding this?

I don't have the option to rewrite the plain Javascript object as it is part of a 3rd party library.

Let me know if I need to provide further clarification and thanks in advance for any guidance!

-- JohnDoe

Comment: What is `JSOBJ` when you try and pass it in? `ng-init` thinks `JSOBJ` is already on the `$scope` if you do it that way.

Comment: If `JSOBJ` is on the global scope then you can just access it directly in your controller.

Comment: @rob You know, I thought that I was able to do it that way. I got a little confused because I started testing this before I included the 3rd party library in my index.html.

Comment: @rob True, but the Angular Way would be to inject it as a dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting it as a value:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .value('JSOBJ', JSOBJ);
```

Then inject it into your controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('GalleryController', ['JSOBJ', function (JSOBJ) { ... }]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since your object is a part of third-party library you have to wrap it app in something angular.

Your options are:

- if it is jquery pluging init'ed for a DOM node etc you can create a `directive`

example

```
 myApp.directive('myplugin', function myPlanetDirectiveFactory()      {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {},
     link: function($scope, $element) { $($element).myplugin() }
   }
});
```

- if it is something you need to init you can use `factory` or `service`

example

```
myApp.service(function() {
  var obj = window.MyLib()

  return {
    do: function() {  obj.do() }
  }
})
```

- if it is plain javascript object you can use `value`

example

```
myApp.value('planet', { name : 'Pluto' } );
```

- if it is constant ( number, string , etc) you can use `constant`

example

```
myApp.constant('planetName', 'Greasy Giant');
```

Reference to this doc page: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Also I strongly encourage you to read answer to this question: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Did you make a mistake with the example "if it is plain javascript object you can use value" ?

Comment: @JohnDoe yes, it was typo it should've been `.value(...)` , fixed answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `JSOBJ` accessible via global scope (via window), than you can access it through `window` directly as in plain JavaScript.

```
<script>
   ...
   window.JSOBJ = {x:1};
   ...
</script>
```

**Option 1.**

```
<script>
  angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.someObject = window.JSOBJ;
  }]);
</script>
```

However it makes the controller code not testable. Therefore `$window` service may be used

**Option 2.**

```
<script>
  angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.someObject = $window.JSOBJ;
  }]);
</script>
```

If you want to make some abstraction layer to make your controller agnostic for the source from where you get the object, it is recommended to define service which is responsible for fetching value and then inject it to your controllers, directives, etc.

**Option 3.**

```
<script>
  angular.module('app',[])
    .service('myService', function() {
      var JSOBJ = ...; // get JSOBJ from anywhere: localStorage, AJAX, window, etc.
      this.getObj = function() {
        return JSOBJ;
      }
     })
    .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
      $scope.someObject = myService.getObj();
    }]);
</script>
```

Besides of it, for simple values you can define `constant` or `value` that may be injected to any controller, service, etc.

**Option 4.**

```
<script>
  angular.module('app',[]).
    value('JSOBJ', JSOBJ).
    controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'JSOBJ', function($scope, JSOBJ) {
      $scope.someObject = JSOBJ;
    }]);
</script>
```